# Why is my value comparison returning false when the values are the same?

Tags: perl

I've got a perl script that loads data from an Excel XLS file into a database.  First, it checks to see if the datetime of the value from the file already exists in the database.  If it does, it checks to see if the value from the file is the same as the value that's in the database.  If they are the same, the value is skipped.  If they are different, the value in the database is updated.

The code that does the comparison is:

```
if($dbVal != $fileVal) {
  &UpdateData($id, $dt, $fileVal);
}
```

The problem is that sometimes, even though the two values 'look' the same, the comparison decides they aren't and the update sub is executed.  Below is an excerpt from a debug log.  For every value from the file, it prints the db value and the file value.  If the update sub gets executed, the "Updating..." line is printed:

```
dbVal = '68800812'; file val = '68800812'
dbVal = '66649164'; file val = '66649164'
Updating:  41248 : 01/01/2011 07:00 : 66649164
dbVal = '64975681'; file val = '64975681'
dbVal = '64037179'; file val = '64037179'
dbVal = '64095165'; file val = '64095165'
dbVal = '64917078'; file val = '64917078'
dbVal = '66584188'; file val = '66584188'
Updating:  41248 : 01/01/2011 12:00 : 66584188
```

So in the above snippet, there were two instances where the db val and the file val look the same but the update sub was executed anyway, meaning the comparison returned true when it looks like it should have been false.

Any thoughts/ideas?

Dave

Comment: Look at the values with `Devel::Peek::Dump` and `sprintf '%.100f'`.

Comment: Looking at the values using `printf` showed the difference.  The value that looked like '66649164' was actually '66649164.000000007450580596923828125' in the file.  >:\

Add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devel::Peek reveals the scalar type NV (float) instead of the expected IV (integer). `sprintf` reveals imprecision, see [Why am I getting long decimals (eg, 19.9499999999999) instead of the numbers I should be getting (eg, 19.95)?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#Why-am-I-getting-long-decimals-eg-19.9499999999999-instead-of-the-numbers-I-should-be-getting-eg-19.95-). When simply printed or used otherwise in string context, the number gets coerced to a representation with a 16 digit mantissa (20-21 if using exponential notation).

Explicitely round the numbers before making a comparison, `sprintf` and [Math::Round](http://p3rl.org/Math%3a%3aRound) are appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your values are treated like strings and one fo the two have an extra space at the beginning/end.

Try this :

```
if($dbVal - $fileVal != 0) {
  &UpdateData($id, $dt, $fileVal);
}
```

Comment: You didn't test that theory, did you? Perl will ignore whitespace when converting strings to numbers.

Comment: Plus, when I print the values to the debug log, I surround the variable name with single-quotes in order to display any leading/trailing spaces.  That's a habit I got into years ago.